# What are the goals for white and black in the Caro Kann exchange variation?

Tags: opening, caro-kann

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 cxd5 4. Bd3 Nc6 5. c3 Nf6 6. Bf4 Bg4 7. Qb3 
Qd7 8. Nd2 e6
```

From this position what is black/white in broad terms attempting to do. What are some clear goals?

Comment: This is not actually the best line for black. Might want to do some digging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that position, both sides will finish development and most likely castle kingside. Then...

White's goals/plans:

Put pressure on the e-file in the interest of forming a kingside attack. This is often done by playing Rfe1 (or Rae1), followed by Ne5. White could then move the d2-knight to f3, bringing it closer to the kingside. After that White will try to continue building up the pressure around the kingside, perhaps even with a Rook lift (i.e., Re3).

Another possible plan of White's is to play c4, accepting an isolated d-pawn in order to open up the game. This plan isn't so common, but it could work if Black's unprepared in the centre.

Black's goals/plans:

Begin a minority attack on the queenside by playing ...Rb8, ...a6, ...b5, and eventually ...b4. By doing this, Black plans to exchange on c3, leaving White with a backwards pawn after White captures back.

Black may also play ...e5, which is the converse of the aforementioned plan for White of playing c4. Black rarely plays the ...e5 plan though, mainly because White just has too much control over that square.

Finally, an important defensive motif for Black often involves maneuvering his light-squared bishop to the g6 square. From here, it blocks the b1-h7 diagonal, neutralizing White's d3-bishop and safeguarding the Black king from attacks.

Answer (score 3):

White normally tries for a king-side attack with the support of a knight on the e5-outpost.

Black has a long-term strategy of the minority attack.  Weakening the c3-pawn by advancing his own queen-side pawns.

This position is the reverse of the Carlbad structure in the QGD - Exchange Variation.  Many good videos about the minority attack on youtube.